# How to properly recompile stored procedures on AWS Redshift

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I need to recompile some stored procedures within my AWS environment, but differently of SQL Server and other DBMS, in Redshift is quite a challenger. After looking at the Redshift documentation, I found nothing useful on stored procedure recompilation regards.

How can I perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer -- more an elaboration of the question.  There doesn't appear to be an explicit "recompile" command but redshift will "automagically" recompile when the query is executed if anything "significant" changed since the last execution.  As to what is "significant" the answer is not clear.  https://zemanta.github.io/2017/03/13/first-steps-with-amazon-redshift/ reports on some experiments.  Obviously if the semantics of the query has changed then it will be recompiled.  But it's not clear (to me anyway) whether the query planner uses table statistics and so might want to recompile if those statistics have changed.  I assume they will recompile if the distibution or sortkeys of a table have changed.  (They don't even tell you that they are recompiling.)  Their attitude seems to be to keep all this under the covers so we won't worry our pretty little heads about it.  (As you can probably tell I find this secrecy quite annoying.)